# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 with Sencha Touch in Windows Phone 8.1 showing errors

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst, senchatouch-2.4

I am using weinre is WEb INspector REmote for debugging IBM Worklight 7.0-sencha touch 2.4 App.

Tested in Windows Phone Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.

1. When Application Starts it Shows :

   ```
   Local storage capacity reached. Client logs will not be persisted
   LocalStorage Quota exceeded, cannot store -x- wmapp0: /www/default/css/app.css locally
   LocalStorage Quota exceeded, cannot store -x-wmapp0:/www/default/app.js locally
   ondeviceready event dispatched
   wlclient init started
   CookieMgr read cookies: {}
   ```
2. When We Call Worklight Adapter WL.Client.invokeProcedure Calls it Shows Errors Like:

   ```
   WL.Utils.getSkinLoaderChecksum(..) should be supported only on environments that support direct update Error: WL.Utils.getSkinLoaderChecksum(..) should be supported only on environments that support direct update.

   [/apps/services/api/myApplication/windowsphone8/query] exception. TypeError: Unable to get property 'notificationTitle' of undefined or null reference

   Uncaught Exception: Unable to get property 'notificationTitle' of undefined or null reference at (compiled_code):3667
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The first error has nothing to do with MobileFirst; if you're using localstorage in your app it seems you have over-used it.

The second error should not happen and sounds like a product defect. You need to open an IBM support ticket (PMR) and provide the following details: full version number (with build number), a test case app that reproduces the error.

Comment: Thank You Idan for the valuable information.We will open a PMR soon.